# Display RecyclerView into fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Good day,

I am trying to display RecyclerView in the fragment of the app. But every time I run the app it crashes. As I understand there is a problem that teamList is on MainActivity and I need to take everything related to teamList to onCreate method at KomandosFragment. But every time I try to do it it just does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Full code in GitHub https://github.com/Kirkoglu/Meginimas

Main Activity:

```
package com.anzelmasfile.meginimas;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.badge.BadgeDrawable;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView teamList;

    String s1[], s2[];
    int images[] = {R.drawable.gargzdai, R.drawable.jonava, R.drawable.joniskis, R.drawable.kaunas,
            R.drawable.klaipeda, R.drawable.marijampole, R.drawable.mazeikiai, R.drawable.moletai,
            R.drawable.palanga, R.drawable.sakiai, R.drawable.silale, R.drawable.silute,
            R.drawable.taurage, R.drawable.telsiai, R.drawable.vilnius};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//
//        teamList = findViewById(R.id.teamList);
//        s1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.komandos);
//        s2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.treneriai);
//
//        KomandosAdapter komandosAdapter = new KomandosAdapter(this, s1, s2, images);
//
//        teamList.setAdapter(komandosAdapter);
//        teamList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        ViewPager2 viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager2.setAdapter(new OrdersPagerAdapter(this));

        final TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        TabLayoutMediator tabLayoutMediator = new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager2, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {

                switch (position) {
                    case 0: {
                        tab.setText("Pradinis");
                        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.pradinis);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 1: {
                        tab.setText("Komandos");
                        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.komandos);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2: {
                        tab.setText("Tvarkaraštis");
                        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.tvarkarastis);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 3: {
                        tab.setText("Rezultatai");
                        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.rezultatai);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 4: {
                        tab.setText("Lentelė");
                        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.lentele);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        });

        tabLayoutMediator.attach();

    }
}
```

KomandosAdapter:

```
package com.anzelmasfile.meginimas;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class KomandosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<KomandosAdapter.KomandosViewHolder> {

    String data1[], data2[];
    int images[];
    Context context;

    public KomandosAdapter(Context ct, String s1[], String s2[], int img[]) {
        context = ct;
        data1 = s1;
        data2 = s2;
        images = img;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public KomandosViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_komandos, parent, false);
        return new KomandosViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull KomandosViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.myText1.setText(data1[position]);
        holder.myText2.setText(data2[position]);
        holder.myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 15;
    }

    public static class KomandosViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView myText1, myText2;
        ImageView myImage;

        KomandosViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myText1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.teamName);
            myText2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.teamCoach);
            myImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.teamLogo);

        }
    }
}
```

KomandosFragment:

```
package com.anzelmasfile.meginimas;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class KomandosFragment extends Fragment {

    public KomandosFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_komandos, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the logcat and add only relevant code

Comment: Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question, try adding logcat, and also what you've tried so far.